# query if on page/2/?

Tags: php, tags

hey guys,
is there a way to check if i'm currently not on the frontpage of my blog?
I know there are conditional tags like is_home(). However that won't work if I'm on myblog.com/page/2/

I have a pagination on my frontpage that let's users jump to the next page. If I'm on the second page i want to show a "Back Home" link.

any idea how I could achieve that?

thank you.

Comment: Since is_home() is a valid tag, can't you just ask if it evaluates to false?  When it's false, put in the link to home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the conditional Tag `is_paged()` for this purpose

Look at: [Codex WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged)